# What is another word for "tip" (as in 'tipping money')?

Tags: word-choice

I've written:

We recommend tipping directly to the person you want to receive the tip.

I don't want to use the word 'tip' at the end of the sentence as I used it earlier on. Is there an alternative word?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial research efforts. For example, looking up *tip* in a thesaurus will provide several possible alternatives, whose use can then check up on in a dictionary. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use *tip* at the end? As the answers point out, *gratuity* could be used here, but, given that *tipping* appears in the first part of the sentence, using *tip* at the end makes it clearer how the two parts are related. Also, *gratuity* may be an overly formal term for the context.

Answer (score 2):

**Gratuity** works. As defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gratuity):

> : something given voluntarily or beyond obligation usually for some
>   service especially : TIP

Answer (score 2):

We recommend tipping directly to the person you want to receive the **gratuity**

And you do not "tip to"; you give a tip to someone or you tip someone.